# Why does this CSS add a scrollbar to my page and remove all the page's content?

Tags: html, css

I created a page with a simple form then added some very basic styling to level things out and it appears to have removed the page content and added a scroll bar.

```
html {
   font-size:1em;   
   }

body {
   background-color: #CCFFCC;
   padding: 0;
   max-width: 100%;
   margin: 100%;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 100%;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 100%;
}

nav li {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rz9Lv837/

Comment: remove the margin: 100% from body tag

Comment: Actually remove all the ´ margin: 100%;´ because you have them in a lot of elements. Do it with something more sensible measurement unit.

Comment: because you have margin 100% everywhere. Remove it and it will sort itself out.

Comment: what did you want `margin: 100%` to do anyway? it's strange :D

Comment: Remove all your margin of 100% and then put up the values according to your plans. But body margin 0 would be good.

Comment: lmfo thanks, I meant to set margin to 0, I'm just tired dont know why I put 100% instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have included margins on the body, header and nav, this is expanding the content out, You could simply fix this by setting the margin to 0 or just removing all instances of margin:100%;

```
html {
    font-size:1em;  
}

body {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav li {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rz9Lv837/3/)

Answer (score 2):

**css**

```
 html {
    font-size: 1em;
}
body {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    padding: 0;
}
nav li {
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rz9Lv837/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

if you want to provide border to your page then try this

```
html {
    font-size:1em;  
}

body {
    background-color: #CCFFCC; 
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border:2px solid grey;
    height:1000px;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav li {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `margin: 100%`. Remove all of those. You don't even need to set a max width to 100%!

```
html {
    font-size:1em;  
}

body {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
    padding: 0;
}

nav li {
    padding: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rz9Lv837/5/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your css :

```
html {
    font-size:1em;  
}

body {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}

header {
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}

nav {
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Kindly note giving margin is in '%' not a good practice, try to make it specific or if you need the page should be responsive so you can use media query or any of the framework.